# Pyspark group by collect list, to_json and pivot

Tags: pyspark

Summary: Combining multiple rows to columns for a user

**Input DF:**

| Id | group | A1 | A2 | B1 | B2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alpha | 1 | 2 | null | null |
| 1 | AlphaNew | 6 | 8 | null | null |
| 2 | Alpha | 7 | 4 | null | null |
| 2 | Beta | null | null | 3 | 9 |

Note: The group values are dynamic

**Expected Output DF:**

| Id | Alpha_A1 | Alpha_A2 | AlphaNew_A1 | AlphaNew_A2 | Beta_B1 | Beta_B2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 8 | null | null |
| 2 | 7 | 4 | null | null | 3 | 9 |

**Attempted Solution:**

I thought of making a json of non-null columns for each row, then a group by and concat_list of maps. Then I can explode the json to get the expected output.

But I am stuck at the stage of a nested json. Here is my code

```
    vcols = df.columns[2:]
    df\
    .withColumn('json', F.to_json(F.struct(*vcols)))\
    .groupby('id')\
    .agg(
       F.to_json(
         F.collect_list(
           F.create_map('group', 'json')
         )
       )
     ).alias('json')
```

| Id | json |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{Alpha: {A1:1, A2:2}}, {AlphaNew: {A1:6, A2:8}}] |
| 2 | [{Alpha: {A1:7, A2:4}}, {Beta: {B1:3, B2:9}}] |

**What I am trying to get:**

| Id | json |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{Alpha_A1:1, Alpha_A2:2, AlphaNew_A1:6, AlphaNew_A2:8}] |
| 2 | [{Alpha_A1:7, Alpha_A2:4, Beta_B1:3, Beta_B2:9}] |

I'd appreciate any help. I'm also trying to avoid UDFs as my true dataframe's shape is quite big

Comment: if pivoting, why does this combination `Alpha_B1`  and `Alpha_B2` not exist? Or is that's part of the requirement?

Comment: @pltc - That is part of the requirement. When pivoting initially, we ignore the null columns for that row.

I could pivot and then drop columns that have only null across all rows. The problem is I have about 76 columns and about 1000 groups. And, I am not sure I would like to pivot all that and scan for columns to drop

Answer (score 2):

There's definitely a better way to do this but I continued your `to json` experiment.

- **Using UDFs**:

After you get something like `[{Alpha: {A1:1, A2:2}}, {AlphaNew: {A1:6, A2:8}}]` you could create a UDF to flatten the dict. But since it's a JSON string you'll have to parse it to `dict` and then back again to JSON.

After that you would like to explode and pivot the table but that's not possible with JSON strings, so you have to use `F.from_json` with defined schema. That will give you `MapType` which you can explode and pivot.

Here's an example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from collections import MutableMapping
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    ArrayType,
    IntegerType,
    MapType,
    StringType,
)


def flatten_dict(d, parent_key="", sep="_"):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten_dict(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)


def flatten_groups(data):
    result = []
    for item in json.loads(data):
        result.append(flatten_dict(item))
    return json.dumps(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Test").getOrCreate()
    data = [
        (1, "Alpha", 1, 2, None, None),
        (1, "AlphaNew", 6, 8, None, None),
        (2, "Alpha", 7, 4, None, None),
        (2, "Beta", None, None, 3, 9),
    ]
    columns = ["Id", "group", "A1", "A2", "B1", "B2"]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
    vcols = df.columns[2:]
    df = (
        df.withColumn("json", F.struct(*vcols))
        .groupby("id")
        .agg(F.to_json(F.collect_list(F.create_map("group", "json"))).alias("json"))
    )

    # Flatten groups
    flatten_groups_udf = F.udf(lambda x: flatten_groups(x))
    schema = ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))
    df = df.withColumn("json", F.from_json(flatten_groups_udf(F.col("json")), schema))

    # Explode and pivot
    df = df.select(F.col("id"), F.explode(F.col("json")).alias("json"))
    df = (
        df.select("id", F.explode("json"))
        .groupby("id")
        .pivot("key")
        .agg(F.first("value"))
    )
```

At the end dataframe looks like:

```
+---+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+-------+                 
|id |AlphaNew_A1|AlphaNew_A2|Alpha_A1|Alpha_A2|Beta_B1|Beta_B2|
+---+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
|1  |6          |8          |1       |2       |null   |null   |
|2  |null       |null       |7       |4       |3      |9      |
+---+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
```

- **Without UDFs**:

```py
vcols = df.columns[2:]
df = (
    df.withColumn("json", F.to_json(F.struct(*vcols)))
    .groupby("id")
    .agg(
        F.collect_list(
            F.create_map(
                "group", F.from_json("json", MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))
            )
        ).alias("json")
    )
)
df = df.withColumn("json", F.explode(F.col("json")).alias("json"))
df = df.select("id", F.explode(F.col("json")).alias("root", "value"))
df = df.select("id", "root", F.explode(F.col("value")).alias("sub", "value"))
df = df.select(
    "id", F.concat(F.col("root"), F.lit("_"), F.col("sub")).alias("name"), "value"
)
df = df.groupBy(F.col("id")).pivot("name").agg(F.first("value"))
```

Result:

```
+---+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+-------+                 
|id |AlphaNew_A1|AlphaNew_A2|Alpha_A1|Alpha_A2|Beta_B1|Beta_B2|
+---+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
|1  |6          |8          |1       |2       |null   |null   |
|2  |null       |null       |7       |4       |3      |9      |
+---+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with this. This worked well. But, I also spent some time finding a non-json approach and have posted my answer in this thread. Let me know if you have any feedback on that

Answer (score 1):

I found a slightly better way than the json approach:

1. Stack the input dataframe value columns A1, A2,B1, B2,.. as rows
   So the structure would look like id, group, sub, value where sub has the column name like A1, A2, B1, B2 and the value column has the value associated
2. Filter out the rows that have value as null
3. And, now we are able to pivot by the group. Since the null value rows are removed, we wont have the initial issue of the pivot making extra columns

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
data = [
        (1, "Alpha", 1, 2, None, None),
        (1, "AlphaNew", 6, 8, None, None),
        (2, "Alpha", 7, 4, None, None),
        (2, "Beta", None, None, 3, 9),
    ]
columns = ["id", "group", "A1", "A2", "B1", "B2"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Value columns that need to be stacked
vcols = df.columns[2:]
expr_str = ', '.join([f"'{i}', {i}" for i in vcols])
expr_str = f"stack({len(vcols)}, {expr_str}) as (sub, value)"

df = df\
.selectExpr("id", "group", expr_str)\
.filter(F.col("value").isNotNull())\
.select("id", F.concat("group", F.lit("_"), "sub").alias("group"), "value")\
.groupBy("id")\
.pivot("group")\
.agg(F.first("value"))

df.show()
```

```
Result:
+---+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| id|AlphaNew_A1|AlphaNew_A2|Alpha_A1|Alpha_A2|Beta_B1|Beta_B2|
+---+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
|  1|          6|          8|       1|       2|   null|   null|
|  2|       null|       null|       7|       4|      3|      9|
+---+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
```